# coercing ANOVA table into table object R

Tags: r, anova, xtable

I am running a lot of ANOVA tables and would ultimately like to run them through the 'xtable' function in the xtable package for export into LaTeX. However I need to supply xtable with a table object, it will not accept an ANOVA object. I basically want to make the ANOVA table as a table object. Here is some reproducable code:

```
utils::data(npk, package="MASS")
npk.aovE <- aov(yield ~  N*P*K + Error(block), npk)
summary(npk.aovE) ## THIS IS THE TABLE I WANT AS A TABLE OBJECT
```

I have tried all the usual suspects (as.table, print and xtable(summary(npk.aoE))) with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does `xtable(npk.aovE)` provide what you want?

Comment: Or perhaps `lapply(summary(npk.aoE), xtable))`

Comment: Yes xtable(npk.aovE) provides what I want! Sorry for the massive over-sight!

Answer (score 1):

Generally what people want is the matrix obtained with:

```
 coef( summary(npk.aovE) )  # which returns NULL
```

As the help page says: "Function `coef` will extract the matrix of coefficients with standard errors, t-statistics and p-values." Unfortunately theory and practice do not always agree. That summary object is actually two dataframes and its behavior is described on `?summary.aovlist` :

```
> summary(npk.aovE)[[2]]
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
N          1 189.28  189.28  12.259 0.00437 **
P          1   8.40    8.40   0.544 0.47490   
K          1  95.20   95.20   6.166 0.02880 * 
N:P        1  21.28   21.28   1.378 0.26317   
N:K        1  33.14   33.14   2.146 0.16865   
P:K        1   0.48    0.48   0.031 0.86275   
Residuals 12 185.29   15.44                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> summary(npk.aovE)[[1]]
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
N:P:K      1   37.0   37.00   0.483  0.525
Residuals  4  306.3   76.57
```